# xdebug in xampp doesn't work on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I try to config xdebug but doesn't work I use:

```
XAMPP 1.7.4  , Netbeans 7.0
Xdebug installed: 2.1.0rc1 
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC6 - Architecture: x86 
Zend Server: no 
PHP Version: 5.3.5 
Zend API nr: 220090626 
PHP API nr: 20090626 
Debug Build: no 
Thread Safe Build: yes 
Configuration File Path: C:\WINDOWS 
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
```

And `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 1
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "DBGp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Now the problems:

Menu attach Debugger is still disabled or grayed out.

When I try to debug the break point is never hit. Scripts run like a normal.

Following is the URL of I get when I click `Debug main project`:

> http://localhost/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

When I close the browser debugger does not stop. It shows the `waiting for connection` status.

When I click the stop debugging button in NetBeans gives a messagebox `There is no connection from xdebug detected with in some seconds` xdebug is not configured or xdebug is not installed.

Please guide me to resolve the above mentioned issues and debug the project.

Answer (score 0):

First are you able to see xdebug in http://localhost/xampp/index.php ? If NOT then probably you are NOT editing the right php.ini file? Seems like XAMPP is using the php.ini file in:

```
c:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
```

Enter your configuration for xdebug in that file, restart Apache and you should be able to connect.

There was no need for me to change anything in Netbeans to get it to work.

Screenshots here: http://rudyegenias.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/xampp-xdebug-xdebug-not-showing-in-phpinfo/

Answer (score 0):

**? to use XDebug on Netbeans & XAMPP**

- use  http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to inspect your system and download best xdebug.dll
- place that .dll in C:/xampp/php/ext
- edit C:/xampp/php/php.ini adding following

`[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.5-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on 
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_host=localhost 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.show_local_vars=on 
xdebug.output_buffering=off`

- restart Apache web server

I've struggled with a lot of other setting but this is best to do the job